# button submit with 2 different behaviour

Tags: javascript

how could i set a variable with a submit button in order to differenciate 2 behaviours, so first time the same submit button will insert in database and in second time it updates database values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your implementation, and if it's ajax..

If ajax, you want to make a note of the fact it's an update somewhere.. perhaps a form element that says so?

```
<input type="hidden" id="formUpdate" value="0" />
```

and on the first submit

```
document.getElementById('formUpdate').value = 1; // and on the submit, check if it's 0 or 1
```

If posting to the server, you can include the  in the code so when the form is submitted again, you can access $_REQUEST['formUpdate'] (such as with php, anyway) ..

hope that helps ya

Comment: thank you it is done well the hidden type resolve perfectelly the problem it is quite nice from you .
thanks again you saved my time.